# How to stop deployment to Heroku in progress

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Is it possible to stop a deploy to Heroku (`git push heroku`) that is currently being built?

Something like `heroku run stopit!`

Btw. rolling back after successful deploy is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: That's good question. I have 5 deploys same time, never seen it's happed

Answer (score 89, accepted):

First, install the [Heroku builds plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds):

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
```

Then, to cancel a build, fetch the list of the recent builds:

```
heroku builds -a YOUR_APP_NAME
```

The first line of the output will be your currently running build, the first column is the build ID.

Cancel it with:

```
heroku builds:cancel BUILD_ID -a YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Et voilà, this will force fail the build.

Note: you could also get the build id from the build log URL.

Answer (score 3):

I might have found an answer to this problem, it seems to have been answered by Heroku in May. I'm assuming that by `release phase` they mean `deploy`:
https://help.heroku.com/Z44Q4WW4/how-do-i-stop-a-release-phase

> Release Phase processes are the same as any other Dyno in your formation, expect they run the codebase from the new release, instead of your current release.
>
> To monitor your Release Phase processes as they execute, you can use the CLI command heroku ps -a YOUR_APP_NAME. as these are normal processes, you can use the ps:kill and ps:scale commands to stop the Release Phase from completing, which in turn, will prevent the latest release from completing.

I haven't tested this yet, but i will update with my exact commands when i have tested it out. If any one tests this out and can confirm, please feel free to update this answer.

Comment: Release Phase runs at the conclusion of the build - it's a place where you'd put things like database migrations or asset compilation tasks.  So I don't think you can use it to stop a build.  You can certainly cancel it with `heroku ps` but by then the build will have finished successfully.

Comment: Wont the effect be that the build will not be used? Or will the new deploy be used? So that i still have to roll back? I should test this one day

Comment: I’m not sure - I think it should fail the build but I will report back once I test it.

Comment: Just confirmed that a build will be used even if the release phase task fails. FWIW this is for a Rails app, with the release phase task a separate shell script that raised an exception inside a rake task.

Comment: The deploy will fail if the release task fails: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#release-command-failure

Comment: It appears there may be some sort of watchdog timer as I tried what @rubendinho said and it took ~ 5 mins before the web process shut down and re-attached the new build

Comment: Link is now in https://help.heroku.com/Z44Q4WW4/how-do-i-stop-a-release-phase

Answer (score 2):

I used the command

```
heroku builds:cancel -a <your_app_name>
```

and this worked for me

Comment: Same here. Didn't have the build number to hand and it was useful to quickly just cancel.